# tsql Group by min and max time for same date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a following data in which each person could have event time-in and event time-out data which can be multiple times in same date as logged for Mike in below code.

```
DECLARE @vtable TABLE 
(
    Id Int NOT NULL, 
    Name VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    EventDate date NOT NULL, 
    EventTime time NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @vtable (Id, Name, EventDate, EventTime)
VALUES (1, 'Mike', '2022-10-10', '08:00'),
       (2, 'Mike', '2022-10-10', '11:00'),
       (3, 'Mike', '2022-10-10', '12:00'),
       (4, 'Mike', '2022-10-10', '18:00'),
       (5, 'Jen', '2022-10-10', '09:00'),
       (6, 'Jen', '2022-10-10', '12:00'),
       (7, 'Jen', '2022-10-11', '14:00'),
       (8, 'Jen', '2022-10-11', '18:00')
```

I tried it with the following query but didn't get the required results:

```
SELECT 
    Name, EventDate, 
    MIN(EventTime) AS In, MAX(EventTime) AS Out 
FROM
    @vtable 
GROUP BY
    Name, EventDate
```

I want to get a result like this:

[image]

Comment: You don't have event kind recorded? And when Mike enters yesterday 23:59, exits today 03:25, then exits again 12:47 (one enter event gets lost), what kind of result do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simplified solution is to use the appropriate grouping:

```
SELECT Name, EventDate, MIN(EventTime) AS [In], MAX(EventTime) AS [Out]
FROM (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, EventDate ORDER BY Id) AS Rn
   FROM @vtable
) t
GROUP BY Name, EventDate, (Rn - 1) / 2
ORDER BY Name, EventDate
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this line `,(Rn - 1) / 2` which is written at the end of `Group by` statement.

Comment: @Zeeshanef, it is an integer division and the result is used as group index. The final result  (for a specific `Name` and `EventDate`) is `0` for the first and the second row (because `(1 - 1) / 2` = `(2 - 1) / 2` = `0`),  `1` for the third and the forth row (because `(3 - 1) / 2` = `(4 - 1) / 2` = `1`) and so on. The idea is to mark each two consecutive
 rows with an unique group index. You may try to execute `SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, EventDate ORDER BY Id) - 1) / 2 AS GroupIndex FROM @vtable` and analyze the results.